# Merge observables from diferent components

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have main component based on 3 sub-components. On main component i have a submit button. But these 3 subcomponent communicate between them and i need disable button then are all services in these components completed. Is possible create some function which will merge running observables (http calls). These components are reactive and if i made some change on someone i need to update another component and during this i need disable button too. In RxJS operators i found merge, forkJoin but there are examples "for one component". But if it isn't possible use these operators i have to find different way.

Answer (score 0):

In host Component define @ViewChild for each nested component and then you'll get access to the nested components APIs.

In nested components define methods which return observables and use them in host component.